# Asp.net Crystal Chart size

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, charts

I have created a crystal report with a chart.  When the report is displayed in the web page the chart is very tiny.  How do I make it larger?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?307bd75311.png][img]http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.307bd75311.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?307bd75311.png][img]http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.307bd75311.png)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/307bd75311.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/307bd75311.png)

---

I solved this problem by using SSRS instead.  I was getting error with MicrosoftReportView in VS2008.   I downloaded SP1 and it works now. Yeah!!!!!!!!

Comment: A screendump could help.

Comment: I added it. See the tiny square with the pie chart in it?

Comment: Yes. What do you use to edit your reports? What is the page size you are using in the report?

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2008 to create the report.   I don't see a page size property.  
I did try changing the width and height properties of the CrystalReportViewer control but it had no effect.